# c++ member function declaration issue w/ class

Tags: c++, class

Below is an extract of the code that I am currently working with (the rest is unrelated to my issue. I am having trouble with the Information combineInfo(information a1) member function. I get an error that it's not declared in the scope. All I want to do is combine the information and set new variables. I was able to this successfully using a structure and now I am self-learning classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

class Information
{
public:
    Information(); 
    void printinformation(); 
    Information combineInfo(Information a1);
    //Setters and Getters Here
private:
    string a;  
    double b; 
    double c; 
    Date d;
    Date e;
};

void initializeDate(Date& d);
void printDate(Date& d);

int main()
{
    cout << endl << "Now please input Information #1" << endl;
    Information a1;  // prompts for all the inputs for a1
    cout << endl << "Now please input Information #2" << endl;
    Information a2;  // prompts for all the inputs for a2
    a2.combineInfo(a1);  // again prompts for info??
    cout << "The combined Information is: " << endl;
    info.printinformation();
    return 0;
}

Information::Information()
{
    string a;
    cout << "Please enter a"<<endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    cout <<"Please enter b?"<<endl;
    cin >> b;
    getline(cin, dummy);
    cout <<"Please enter c?"<<endl;
    cin >> c;
    getline(cin, dummy);
    cout << "Please input the info start dates."<< endl;
    initializeDate(start);
    cout << "Please input the info end dates."<< endl;
    initializeDate(finish);
}

Information Information::combineInfo(Information a1)
{
    Information a1;
    Information a2;
    Information info;
    a1.a = a2.a;
   //etc.
    return info;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives a lot of compilation errors, but the weirdest part is here:

```
    Information a2;
    a2.:combineInfo(a1);
//    ^^ Remove the :

    cout << "The combined Information is: " << endl;
    info.printinformation();
//  ^^^^
//  You didn't declare info
```

Comment: When I do `information a2` in `main` it prompts for all the info that goes into it. Then when I run a2.combineInfo(a1) it again prompts for some information. I'm not sure why and it mustn't do that. It compiles fine on my end, perhaps I missed some critical parts when I extracted what I thought was most important.

Comment: @user2163231: The code prompting for some information is in the constructor of the `Information` class. I thought you were aware of what you wrote in there

Comment: I run Information a1 and information a2 and it prompts for info through a constructor and that works fine. Then when I run a2.combineInfo(a1) it again prompts for some information instead of just combining and setting some variables equal. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user2163231: You're constructing two new instances of `Information` inside `combineInfo()`. So you call the constructor twice. And you're asked for information twice. Probably you want to pass by reference

Comment: could you please show me in pastebin the general idea of what you mean by 'call the constructor twice?` For this exercise I should not use pass by reference.

Comment: @user2163231: I think I do not have enough time to explain you these basic things, maybe you should read some tutorial on classes, constructors, member functions, etc.

Comment: It's just 2 lines of code that I'm missing. I'm not sure why '   a2.combineInfo(a1); prompts for more information. Perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: @user2163231: As I wrote, `combineInfo()` does this: `Information a1;     Information a2; Information info;`. It creates three objects of type `Information`. It means the constructor of `Information` is called three times. This means you're prompted for that stuff 3 times.

Comment: Sorry must have missed where you wrote that! Hmm, I'll think about this some more. Based on what your saying it sounds like I shouldn't have Information a1; and Information a2 separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
a2.:combineInfo(a1);
```

It should be:

```
a2.combineInfo(a1);
```

There's an extra ':' in there by mistake.